# Перенос значений из одного dataGridView в другой dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно перенести данные колонки из одного dataGridView в другой по условию, если есть какой-нибудь примерчик, то напишите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если понял вопрос правильно. Итак, есть два DataGridView. Хотим выделить в одном данные, например, строки и перенести их в другой.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in fromDGV.SelectedRows)
{
     object[] items = new object [row.Cells.Count];
     for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++) {
         items[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
     }
     toDGV.Rows.Add(items);
     fromDGV.Rows.Delete(row);
}
```